# focus in a cell value of DataGridView C# windows forms on adding a row

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` . When I click on a button a row gets added into the `DataGridView`. There are 3 columns named 'Rate','Qty' and 'Total'. On adding a row, by default full row is selected. How can I focus on a 'Qty' column by default so that I need not move mouse there to edit the cell value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following this:

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell =  DataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex]
```

or

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Item("ColumnName", 1)
```

and you can directly focus on Editing by:

```
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true)
```